# wordpress on openshift custom domain "too many redirects" error, works on openshift default domain

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, openshift

wordpress on openshift custom domain "too many redirects" error, works on openshift default domain

curl request on custom domain does not work

curl -vvv http://www.hobbyhap.com/h

```
            Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
            *   Trying 54.204.79.83...
            * Connected to www.hobbyhap.com (54.204.79.83) port 80 (#0)
            > GET /h HTTP/1.1
            > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
            > Host: www.hobbyhap.com
            > Accept: */*
            > 
            < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
            < Date: Tue, 27 Jan 2015 18:05:15 GMT
            * Server Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) is not blacklisted
            < Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
            < Location: http://www.hobbyhap.com/h/
            < Content-Length: 317
            < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
            < Cache-control: private
            < Set-Cookie: GEAR=local-54c70ac64382ec8161000031; path=/
            < Accept-Ranges: none
            < 
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
            <html><head>
            <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
            </head><body>
            <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
            <p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.hobbyhap.com/h/">here</a>.</p>
            <hr>
            <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at www.hobbyhap.com Port 80</address>
            </body></html>
            * Connection #0 to host www.hobbyhap.com left intact
```

curl request on openshift domain works

curl -vvv http://hhapp-hobbyhap.rhcloud.com/h/

Comment: Did you change the name in your WordPress installation to listen on www.hobbyhap.com ?

Comment: You mean update the site and site_meta table, with the www.hobbyhap.com?

Comment: Yes, I already updated site and site_meta tables for wp with www.hobbyhap.com

Answer (score 1):

I update blogs,options,site and sitemeta tables with the custom domain,and it started working